# Is it safe to trust request.local? for authentication in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security

I have an API controller in a Rails 3 application that is used to communicate with other applications on the same machine and remote servers.

Remote servers use HTTP basic authentication to gain access to the API. Requests originating from the same server should be allowed by default.

Is is safe to trust request.local? that requests are really coming from the same machine? I am thinking of IP spoofing etc.

Btw "protect_from_forgery" is deactivated in the API controller.

Answer (score 0):

For a moderate level of security, yes.  This requires that you trust all processes that may run on the same system by any user.  It also requires the servers TCP/IP stack, routes, and network filters/internal firewall be configured in a sane way that doesn't allow packets originating from outside the server to be masqueraded as a local IP address (specifically 127.0.0.1).  And it assumes that the `LOCALHOST` constant in Rails be set to `127.0.0.1`.

By the way, `protect_from_forgery` protects from [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (CSRF) and does not and cannot protect against IP address spoofing.  And ensuring that a request is coming from an authorized IP and user does not protect against CSRF.